# round up/down float to 2 decimals

Tags: python, floating-point, rounding

I would like to design a function `f(x : float, up : bool)` with these input/output:

```
# 2 decimals part rounded up (up = True)
f(142.452, True) = 142.46
f(142.449, True) = 142.45
# 2 decimals part rounded down (up = False)
f(142.452, False) = 142.45
f(142.449, False) = 142.44
```

Now, I know about Python's `round` built-in function but it will always round `142.449` up, which is not what I want.

Is there a way to do this in a nicer pythonic way than to do a bunch of float comparisons with epsilons (prone to errors)?

Comment: This almost looks like it might work better as a string operation.

Comment: Or maybe use `ceil` and `floor`  after moving the decimal

Comment: round() already does what you want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you considered a mathematical approach using `floor` and `ceil`?

If you always want to round to 2 digits, then you could premultiply the number to be rounded by 100, then perform the rounding to the nearest integer and then divide again by 100.

```
from math import floor, ceil

def rounder(num, up=True):
    digits = 2
    mul = 10**digits
    if up:
        return ceil(num * mul)/mul
    else:
        return floor(num*mul)/mul
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also perform some mathematical logic if you do not want to use any explicit function as:

```
def f(num, up):
    num = num * 100
    if up and num != int(num):  # if up and "float' value != 'int' value
        num += 1
    return int(num) / (100.0)
```

Here, the idea is if `up` is `True` and `int` value of number is not equal to `float` value then increase the number by 1. Else it will be same as the original number

Answer (score 0):

`math.ceil()` rounds up, and `math.floor()` rounds down.  So, the following is an example of how to use it:

```
import math

def f(x, b):
    if b:
        return (math.ceil(100*x) / 100)
    else:
        return (math.floor(100*x) / 100)
```

This function should do exactly what you want.