# How to turn a flout number as 17,8999 into 17,8 without rolling in python?

Tags: python, rounding

How can I get this result? I tried using round but I do not want to role number like 16.6 into 16.7. I just want number to written after comma only 1 number like 17.8999 into 17.8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [round up/down float to 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40613590/round-up-down-float-to-2-decimals)

Comment: Look at the Decimal class. You can not get a float to reliably  represent accurately a single decimal other than 0.0 and 0.5 because 0.1 can't be accurately represented as a float.

Comment: Could you post your code so we can see what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 3):

convert to an integer and back to float: `x = int(17.89999 * 10) / 10`